# Where in the hindu sacred texts does it say animals do not create new karma?

Tags: gods, karma, animals

Where in the hindu texts does it say that animals and the gods do not create new karma but only pay off karma?

Comment: I think scriptures doesn't say that, but they say only that the other planets (lokas) which are not this earth, and other species of life which are not humans on earth (such as plants, insects, animals, beings living in heavens, gods such as Indra, etc), are all just enjoying and suffering their past karma which they made on this earth, and this earth is the place where jivatmas make great quantities of karma.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda had mentioned in detail about the karma of animals, devas and humans.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate...